# How to save throught model with extra field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models `Company`, `User` and `Division`

`User` have many `Division` for different `Companies`

I need to determine in what company owns Divisions

So I build `has_many :through` association between `Users` and `Divisions`

Model `UsersDivision` have this fields `id|user_id|division_id|company_id` but when I update User model rails delete old records and create new without `company_id` field How i can update model `UsersDivision` and merge `company_id`  ?

Callback?

```
class UsersDivision < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_update :set_company

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :company

  validates :user_id, :division_id, presence: true

  private

  def set_company(company)
    self.company_id = company
  end
end
```

or in the controller?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end 
end
```

How to merge company_id when create UsersDivision record?

Answer (score 0):

> So I build `has_many :through` association between `Users` and `Divisions`

I would expect there to be a table for `Divisions`, and then a table for `CompanyDivisions`, and then we can associate users to that.

Here's how I would have it set up:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_divisions
   has_many :divisions, through: :user_divisions
   has_many :company_divisions, through: :user_divisions
   has_many :companies, through: :company_divisions
end

#app/models/user_division.rb
class UserDivision < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :company_division
end

#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :company_divisions
   has_many :divisions, through: :company_divisions
end

#app/models/company_division.rb
class CompanyDivision < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :division
end

#app/models/division.rb
class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :company_divisions
   has_many :companies, through: :company_divisions
end
```

This is very bloated, but should give you the ability to call:

```
@user.divisions
@user.divisions.each do |division|
   division.companies.first
```

---

> How to merge `company_id` when create `UsersDivision` record

This will depend on several factors:

> 1. `params` hash
> 2. How your associations are set up

I don't have your params hash, but I do have your current code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @company = Company.find params[:company_id]
    @user = User.find params[:id]

    redirect_to :back if @user.update user_params
  end 

  private

  def user_params
     params.require(___).permit(___).merge(company_id: @company.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank's i tried use merge method ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#update unknown attribute: company_id,